# How to update a component's prop which has been saved in a const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

I have a parent component which is like this :

```
function parentComponent(){
     const [selectedValue,setSelectedValue] = useState();
     
     const [renderComponent,setRenderComponent] =[
           {
            name:'A' ,
            component : <ChildComponent values={selectedValue}/>
           },
           {
            name:'B' ,
            component : <OtherComponent/>
           },
     ]
     
    useEffect(()=>{
    
     const response = api('someapi');
     //i can get the response correctly and save it to state
     if(response.status===200){
     setSelectedValue(response.data);
     }
    },[])

    return <>{renderComponent[0].component}</>
     
}
```

and my child component is :

```
function childComponent({values}){
console.log('Props value is : ', values)

return <h3>Something</h3>

}
```

The problem is props are not updating and continue to return 'undefined' even after I update the state from the parent component

Comment: There are couple of problems in the code: 1- renderComponent is not an array, you should use it like `renderComponent.component ` 2- childComponent must be `ChildComponent`

Comment: Thanks for cooperating saeed joon :}

Comment: You're welcome dear :)

Comment: let's chat here : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240671/update-prop

Comment: i can't use chat room because my reputation rate is under 20

Comment: how about another platform? like linkedin, ...

Answer (score -1):

```
 

     useEffect(()=>{
       //set your state only after api data is completely fetched
   
         api('someapi').then((response)=>{
         console.log(response);// make sure this is not undefined
   
    if(response.status===200){
        setSelectedValue(response.data); 
        }
   }); 
   },[])
```